# jQuery text acting on duplicate classes

Tags: jquery

I have two buttons, one of class "button white" and another one of class "button white small". In jQuery every time i click one button the text is changing to both of my buttons:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$(".button.white").click(function () {                    
  $('.button.white').text('Added');
  });
});
```

How can i avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".button.white").click(function () {                    
    $(this).text('Added');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `this` to fetch the button that was clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $(".button.white").click(function () {
        $(this).text('Added');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This happen becouse it think every word is a diffrent class.
use your class as button-white and button-white-small'(without blanks)
and in your code write:

```
$(".button-white").click(function () {                    
   $(this).text('Added');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A starting point, I would try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $(".button.white").click(function () {                    
    $('.button.white').not(".small).text('Added');
    });
});
```

TO remove the .small entry.

(Unchecked, as I don't have access to test ATM.)